# Как посчитать факториал большого числа?

Tags: алгоритм

Как посчитать факториал большого числа в случае, когда размерности типа не хватает? Например, 50! или 100!. Какими методами это можно обойти?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java- [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)
Python- [Длинные числа](http://fantom-lab.narod.ru/Python/LerningNoName/Chapter-03/03.htm)
C++ - [BigInteger](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)
PHP- [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: `@ReinRaus первые две ссылки видимо обновились, выдают ошибку.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за замечание. Это ответ- ссылка со времен хэшкода. Приведу в достойный вид этот ответ ближе к ночи.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, можно использовать длинную арифметику (т.е. мы наше число-результат храним не в каком-то типе long или int, а просто, например, его цифры в десятичной записи в качестве ячеек некоторого массива, который представляет число). О реализации такого метода можно почитать тут: [Длинная арифметика](http://olympbrain.com/theory/ext_theory.aspx?ext_page=MiuHE7eIe9vPHSifYhEBSrW4VyTcOccKW/hXXBWH17cf7M/oBfZI/siC+td5oIdG)

Длинная арифметика реализована на Java в классе BigInteger в пакете Math (если не ошибаюсь). В других языках она тоже есть, как ответил [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)

Другой вариант - считать ответ по модулю (т.е. выдать остаток от деления факториала на некоторое число). Тогда, каждый раз домножая на определённое число при подсчёте факториала нужно [пользоваться формулой](http://olympbrain.com/theory/mod_mul2mul.aspx). Так мы не допустим переполнение типа.

Если нужно выдать только, например, 8 последних цифр факториала, то можно искать остаток от деления на 10^8.

Answer (score 0):

На [python](/questions/tagged/python) это очень просто сделать, т.к. нет ограничения размера чисел:

```py
def f(n):
    return n * f(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1

print(f(5))
# 120

print(f(0))
# 1

print(f(50))
# 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000

print(f(100))
# 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

print(f(500))
# 1220136825991110068701238785423046926253574342803192842192413588385845373153881997605496447502203281863013616477148203584163378722078177200480785205159329285477907571939330603772960859086270429174547882424912726344305670173270769461062802310452644218878789465754777149863494367781037644274033827365397471386477878495438489595537537990423241061271326984327745715546309977202781014561081188373709531016356324432987029563896628911658974769572087926928871281780070265174507768410719624390394322536422605234945850129918571501248706961568141625359056693423813008856249246891564126775654481886506593847951775360894005745238940335798476363944905313062323749066445048824665075946735862074637925184200459369692981022263971952597190945217823331756934581508552332820762820023402626907898342451712006207714640979456116127629145951237229913340169552363850942885592018727433795173014586357570828355780158735432768888680120399882384702151467605445407663535984174430480128938313896881639487469658817504506926365338175055478128640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score -1):

[Вот тута есть ответ](http://ru.techerald.com/page/alguien-puede-explicar-este-algoritmo-para-calcular-factoriales-grandes.html)

Когда поступал на работу выдали тестовле задание, вот как я его сделал:
Java
        package com.pack.fac;

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial {

    public static BigInteger problem20(int max){
        //amount of received items
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        //result 
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

        for(long i = 1; i<=max; i++){
            result  = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        while (!result.equals(0)) {
            sum = sum.add(result.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10)));
            result = result.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
            System.out.println(sum + " "+ result);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        problem20(100);  //число из которого нужно взять факториал
    }
}
```

Comment: Второй цикл явно лишний.

Comment: Чё ж это за работа такая халявная? :)